# Anaconda Prompt(Anaconda3) does not recognize files in a directory

Tags: prompt

I took to heart the message that support for anaconda2 was dropped. I installed anaconda3 and used 2to3 to convert my *.py codes. Everything seemed to work as expected. I have several 2 line bat codes that cd to a particular directory and then call python to execute a particular *.py code in that directory. By loading Anaconda Prompt(Anaconda3) and invoking the bat file I could run pythons in that directory as expected.

Then, a couple of days ago, I made such a run and got an error message saying the *.py file could not be found. I immediately looked in the directory and the python file was there as expected. I then did a dir command in Anaconda Prompt(Anaconda3) and found that almost no files in the directory were listed. This was happening on my windows 10 laptop.

On my desktop, everything continues to work as expected. Are there any suggestions as to what could cause such a problem and how to fix it.

Thanks,
Mack Elrod

Responding to the request for additional information, I have a bin directory that is in path. In bin\MackData.bat is

c:
cd %USERPROFILE%\Documents\Medev\MackData
copy sugarhist.png sugarhist.old.png
python MackData.py

When I open Anaconda Prompt(Anaconda3) and enter MackData I get

(base) C:\Users\Mack>MackData

(base) C:\Users\Mack>c:

(base) C:\Users\Mack>cd C:\Users\Mack\Documents\Medev\MackData

(base) C:\Users\Mack\Documents\Medev\MackData>copy sugarhist.png sugarhist.old.png
        1 file(s) copied.

(base) C:\Users\Mack\Documents\Medev\MackData>python MackData.py
python: can't open file 'MackData.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

(base) C:\Users\Mack\Documents\Medev\MackData>

But MackData.py is a python file in the directory MackData.

This code worked on this laptop until a few days ago and continues to work on my desktop computer. I can, of course, publish MackData.py but that seems irrelevant. The point is that Anaconda can't find it.

Thanks,
Mack

I must submit a sincere apology to this community. I have determined my problem and Anaconda is **not** responsible in any way. I thank all of you for you concerns and comments.

For any who might be interested I will give a brief outline of what happened. First, I installed Anaconda3. Several days later my directory, MackData, was moved to a new location. I conjecture that happened by me inadvertently letting my hand drag on the touch pad. Then, not knowing the location had changed I updated my laptop from my desktop. My update program not finding MackData where expected recreated it and put only the most recently changed files from the desktop into the new MackData. New but in the correct location. Then of course running my script in the Anaconda3 prompt failed. Doing a dir in the Anaconda3 prompt showed only a few files were there. I then went to Windows File Explore and looked at MackData and saw all of the expected files. I used the quick access feature which unknown to me pointed to the old directory in its new location.

That is not intended to be an excuse but only as an explanation. Again, I do apologize to the community.

Mack Elrod

Comment: Can you post the code, the error code and your bat files?

Comment: bin\MackData.bat contains

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure newer anaconda launchers users different environment paths, and not even windows ones.

I suggest either checking the environment path within the anaconda launcher and configurations or, a better solution in my opinion, run these scrips using the regular python engine, without using anaconda (simpler, more determinant and works within your standard environment)